# Everyday examples of hydraulic pressure drop generating heat

Tags: thermodynamics, hydraulics, power

I'm interested in hands-on examples of voltage drop in electronics dissipating the energy as heat, and, thought that the hydraulics analogy, that is the same thing, might be a good way to intuitively understand it. Are there any every day examples where a pipe tends to overheat from friction when pressure loss is too great? Such that if you touch it, it is really hot. I was thinking maybe there are lots that I don't think of, so I ask here.

Comment: Friction of some materials carried by pipes will wear holes especially at bends.

Comment: maybe it might become noticeable in unusual situations with skinny lines and relatively viscous hydraulic fluids?? Or inside a pump, I don't know if that would count for your question. I had a project calibrating sensors for a very viscous (12000 CSt, honey-like) medical lubricant, and it heated up after many passes through the measurement system with ~2mm inside diameter plumbing, by maybe 1 or 2 degrees C. And I don't know how much of it was heat picked up from the measuring device vs flow. But I think maybe some of it was actually from the friction.

Comment: @PeteW Thanks, I was looking mostly for "hands on" examples from hydraulics, and your example fits, maybe it was from friction. Interesting. Found a few patents for heaters based on friction from hydraulic resistance too, https://patents.google.com/patent/US4462386A/en, and also managed to get up to speed with electronics examples after that. I just prefer to connect knowledge to something I already understand, easier that way, faster. Peace.

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks, that the same friction generating heat and not some cavitation effect like what destroys propellers on boats and stuff? overall I think I got up to speed with the concepts, I^2*R, and appreciate the feedback I got.

Answer (score 1):

That's not going to work. The same flow that should run buy so fast to create heat by friction will take away any heat on the surface of the pipe, even so fast, that instant water heaters use this technology to provide hot water for household consumption.

For example, in a car radiator, hot engine water circulating in the radiator of a car will lose its heat to the pipe and next, the pipe to ambient air.

Comment: ah ok, I was thinking there might not be any clear examples. I get the point anyway, P = I^2*R, double the resistance should produce exactly twice the heat. there are a few patents for different "frictional heaters" that look like they might use that, https://patents.google.com/patent/US4462386A/en